# Find all permutations of List<List<double>>

Tags: c#, permutation

I've got a situation in which I need to find all permutations of a List of lists of doubles like the following:

```
List<double> A = new List<double>(){ 1, 2, 3};
List<double> B = new List<double>(){ 10, 20, 30};
List<double> C = new List<double>(){ 100, 200, 300};
```

needs to give me:

{(1,10,100),(1,10,200),(1,10,300),(1,20,100),(1,20,200),(1,20,300)...}

I can do it for a fixed number of lists, but I want the flexibility (and neatness) of a generalised solution.  I've found answers that deal with permutations of a single list, but nothing taking one option from each list, as shown above.

Comment: Why do you show code that does not compile? Do you have so little time( but we have )?

Comment: See: [Computing a Cartesian Product with LINQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx) from Eric Lippert's blog.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Just trying to give you an idea of what I mean.  Also, fixed some typos.

Comment: Do you also want the "1, 2, 3" to appear, or just do it across the lists?

Comment: @LukeHennerley Just across the lists.

Comment: @elevenThousand_dB I suspect that all lists will have to be the same length; in this case 3. Otherwise you could end up with `4, null, null`.

Comment: I wouldn't think they all have to have the same length. You can generate all combinations of items taken from a set of lists of different lengths. Assuming he means that he wants the the n-ary Cartesian Product (as defined at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on Ani's comment: I also use Eric Lippert's solution for this kind of thing. (I only really use it for unit testing all possible combinations of small amounts of data.)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    public static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var a = new List<double> { 1, 2, 3 };
            var b = new List<double> { 10, 20, 30 };
            var c = new List<double> { 100, 200, 300 };

            var lists = new List<List<double>> {a, b, c};

            foreach (var combination in Combine(lists))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(asString(combination));
            }
        }

        static string asString(IEnumerable<double> data)
        {
            return "(" + string.Join(",", data) + ")";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Calculates the n-ary Cartesian Product (i.e. all possible combinations) of items taken from any
        /// number of sequences.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the items in the sequences.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="sequences">The sequences to combine.</param>
        /// <returns>An enumerator that yields all possible combinations of items.</returns>
        /// <remarks>
        /// This code is taken from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx
        /// 
        /// If the sequences are ABC and 123, the output will be A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3.
        /// </remarks>

        public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combine<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
        {
            IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };

            return sequences.Aggregate(
              emptyProduct,
              (accumulator, sequence) =>
                from accseq in accumulator
                from item in sequence
                select accseq.Concat(new[] { item }));
        }
    }
}
```